# How to disable other months days in QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qcalendarwidget

I am aiming to disable that users can click on days that aren't from the current month in a `QCalendarWidget`, so I subclassed the widget in order to do it. So far I could make those days don't render any text at all (great). This is the code:

```
class QCustomCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    """Create my own Calendar with my own options."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initializing functions"""
        QCalendarWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setEnabled(True)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 320, 250))
        self.setGridVisible(False)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.SingleLetterDayNames)
        self.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.setNavigationBarVisible(True)
        self.setDateEditEnabled(True)
        self.setObjectName("calendarWidget")

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        """Sub-class this and repaint the cells"""
        # Render only this-month days
        month = "{0}-{1}".format(str(self.yearShown()), str(self.monthShown()).zfill(2))
        day = str(date.toPython())
        if not day.startswith(month):
            return
        QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
```

However, if I click on a non-rendered day it still counts and triggers the `clicked` event. Example: I photoshopped a red square where clicking in it, it would select June's 4th (even though we are in May in the screenshot).

[image: Example]

**How do I disable those days to not being selectables?**

I tried `setDateRange` on `currentPageChanged` event, but it doesn't works as expected:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    # some code
    self.currentPageChanged.connect(self.store_current_month)
    self.clicked.connect(self.calendar_itemchosen)

def store_current_month(self):
    self.CURRENT_MONTH = "{0}-{1}".format(str(self.yearShown()), str(self.monthShown()).zfill(2))

def calendar_itemchosen(self):
    day = str(self.selectedDate().toPython())
    print(day)
    if day.startswith(self.CURRENT_MONTH):
        selection = self.selectedDate()
        # some code
        self.close()
```

The result of clicking on that red square with this code is:

```
2018-06
2018-06-04
```

So I guess Qt first triggers the `currentPageChanged` event when you select a date on another month. `setDateRange` won't work because if I add it to limit selections to this month only, then the buttons at top of the calendar to "go to next or previous month" won't work, and I need the user to be able to change months. I just don't want the calendar to show days that don't belong to this month page.

Comment: I understand what you want, but if the other months or days are disabled (that's what you want) what would you observe when you press the buttons that are on the top that serve to *go to next or previous month*?

Comment: Nothing happens, if I use `setDateRange` those buttons are disabled. I want those buttons to not be disabled.

Comment: I think you did not understand me, I understand that that is not the solution, what I indicate is that those buttons must also be disabled since they will not serve the user at all since the next or previous page will not have anything.

Comment: Now that you mention, it makes sense. What approach should I take then?

Comment: My idea is to disable the buttons plus the remaining days of the other months.

Comment: My intention is to be able to go to other months. I think you did not understand me. If I am in May I want to be able to only select 1-31 days of May, but not June's 1. But I move to June manually (top buttons) I want to be able to select only June days 1-31 but not May 31th (as example). I only want to select the "current month" days, but being able to move to different months.

Comment: Okay, now I understand you a lot better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to filter the mousePressEvent event of the QTableView that the QCalendarWidget has Internally. For this we use the event filter:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class CalendarWidget(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).__init__(parent, gridVisible=False,
            horizontalHeaderFormat=QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.SingleLetterDayNames,
            verticalHeaderFormat=QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader,
            navigationBarVisible=True,
            dateEditEnabled=True)       
        self.setEnabled(True)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 250))
        self.clicked.connect(print)

        self.table_view = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QTableView, "qt_calendar_calendarview")
        self.table_view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.setFirstDayOfWeek(QtCore.Qt.Monday)

    def referenceDate(self):
        refDay = 1
        while refDay <= 31:
            refDate = QtCore.QDate(self.yearShown(), self.monthShown(), refDay)
            if refDate.isValid(): return refDate
            refDay += 1
        return QtCore.QDate()

    def columnForDayOfWeek(self, day):
        m_firstColumn = 1 if self.verticalHeaderFormat() != QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader else 0
        if day < 1 or day > 7: return -1
        column = day - int(self.firstDayOfWeek())
        if column < 0:
            column += 7
        return column + m_firstColumn

    def columnForFirstOfMonth(self, date):
        return (self.columnForDayOfWeek(date.dayOfWeek()) - (date.day() % 7) + 8) % 7

    def dateForCell(self, row, column):
        m_firstRow = 1 if self.horizontalHeaderFormat() != QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoHorizontalHeader else 0
        m_firstColumn = 1 if self.verticalHeaderFormat() != QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader else 0
        rowCount = 6
        columnCount = 7
        if row < m_firstRow or row > (m_firstRow + rowCount -1) or column < m_firstColumn or column > (m_firstColumn + columnCount -1):
            return QtCore.QDate()
        refDate = self.referenceDate()
        if not refDate.isValid():
            return QtCore.QDate()
        columnForFirstOfShownMonth = self.columnForFirstOfMonth(refDate)
        if (columnForFirstOfShownMonth - m_firstColumn) < 1:
            row -= 1
        requestedDay = 7*(row - m_firstRow) +  column  - columnForFirstOfShownMonth - refDate.day() + 1
        return refDate.addDays(requestedDay)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.table_view.viewport() and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:    
            ix = self.table_view.indexAt(event.pos())
            date = self.dateForCell(ix.row(), ix.column())
            d_start = QtCore.QDate(self.yearShown(), self.monthShown(), 1)
            d_end = QtCore.QDate(self.yearShown(), self.monthShown(), d_start.daysInMonth())
            if d_start > date or date > d_end:
                return True
        return super(CalendarWidget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        d_start = QtCore.QDate(self.yearShown(), self.monthShown(), 1)
        d_end = QtCore.QDate(self.yearShown(), self.monthShown(), d_start.daysInMonth())
        if d_start <= date <= d_end:
            super(CalendarWidget, self).paintCell(painter, rect, date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So far it works great, except for a case. The first day of each month is not selectable (and the first day of next month it's selectable, it shouldn't). I assume that's because of `if d_start <= date <= d_end` so I'll fix it myself. Just letting you know. Once I make sure this is what I needed I'll accept this answer as valid.

Comment: @Saelyth Are you sure ?, I do not have that problem, you could say the exact dates that generate that problem Have you tested my code or an adaptation to your code?

Comment: I had to adapt the code because my calender is quite complicated (it uses lot of QPainterPath, RoundedRect and stuff like that to set specific notes on specific days). My first comment to this answer was wrong. The paintCell function works as expected. The issue must be somewhere else, I keep investigating.

Comment: @Saelyth I see that your week starts on Monday(Lunes) but mine on Sunday(Domingo), I think that is the error. :-)

Comment: Oh, might be. Yeah, but I shouldn't change that, everything would fall apart (and in my country weeks start on monday). BTW: Just for fun, these are the notes why I have to adapt the code: https://image.prntscr.com/image/3euWD8_zTb_Tfh81Q6RlAg.png

Comment: Thank you for the help. I editted your code and added a Note with the fix for the problem if monday is the first day.

Comment: @Saelyth reject your edition because implement a general solution.

Comment: Hey @Eyllanesc I just found out a issue with this code. 2018 October shows as this and I can't click on days 25 to 31, but oddly I can click on any day of the the empty first row: https://image.prntscr.com/image/IPI8V0BST7KmQtaNtXEjwg.png I tried to fix it myself with no luck.

Comment: @Saelyth Are you using my latest code ?, I remember updating it by eliminating certain bugs, and I just tried the date indicated and it works correctly.

Comment: Oh damn I missed your last update. Thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: At least in Pyside2 there's a bug for `columnForDayOfWeek` function. I can't seem to fix it. `column = day - self.firstDayOfWeek()`always returns 0. Probably because `FirstDayOfWeek` is different. I had to set this on the init `self.setFirstDayOfWeek(Qt.DayOfWeek(1))`

Comment: @Saelyth Do you understand now the importance of the tags ?, PySide2 is not PyQt5, so it is always advisable to point out one of them and not both, I am going to test it later

Comment: Yup, that's a lesson for me. I won't tag the wrong one anymore, as this code is giving me so much issues. Thank you for the constant help.

Comment: @Saelyth I only changed `self.setFirstDayOfWeek(1)` to `self.setFirstDayOfWeek(QtCore.Qt.Monday)` and it works correctly in PySide2 5.12 on Linux, and column does not always return 0

Comment: Oddly enough I had to convert it to integer for it to work: `column = day - int(self.firstDayOfWeek())` I guess it's because I'm on windows or I don't get it. Also PySide 5.12. Everything is fine now.